# IE is ignoring FacesContext.responseComplete()

Tags: jsf

Why IE (IE8) is still trying to render the current page after FacesContext.responseComplete() is called immediately after the page is re-directed to another page using Response.sendRedirect().  Other browsers (Firefox, Chrome, Opera...) just jump to another page without trying to render the current page.  I am using JSF 1.2 with Richfaces 3.3 final.  JSF life cycles are listed below for a command button being triggered.  Please notice the validation phase on IE.  Is the validation the root cause?

**Other browsers**

Before RESTORE_VIEW 1

After RESTORE_VIEW 1

Before APPLY_REQUEST_VALUES 2

After APPLY_REQUEST_VALUES 2

Before PROCESS_VALIDATIONS 3

After PROCESS_VALIDATIONS 3

Before UPDATE_MODEL_VALUES 4

After UPDATE_MODEL_VALUES 4

Before INVOKE_APPLICATION 5

After INVOKE_APPLICATION 5

Before RENDER_RESPONSE 6

After RENDER_RESPONSE 6

Before RESTORE_VIEW 1

After RESTORE_VIEW 1

Before RENDER_RESPONSE 6

After RENDER_RESPONSE 6

**IE**

Before RESTORE_VIEW 1

After RESTORE_VIEW 1

Before APPLY_REQUEST_VALUES 2

After APPLY_REQUEST_VALUES 2

Before PROCESS_VALIDATIONS 3

After PROCESS_VALIDATIONS 3

Before UPDATE_MODEL_VALUES 4

After UPDATE_MODEL_VALUES 4

Before INVOKE_APPLICATION 5

After INVOKE_APPLICATION 5

Before RENDER_RESPONSE 6

After RENDER_RESPONSE 6

Before RESTORE_VIEW 1

After RESTORE_VIEW 1

Before APPLY_REQUEST_VALUES 2

After APPLY_REQUEST_VALUES 2

Before PROCESS_VALIDATIONS 3

*... errors (not related to the question)*

After PROCESS_VALIDATIONS 3

Before RESTORE_VIEW 1

After RESTORE_VIEW 1

Before RENDER_RESPONSE 6

After RENDER_RESPONSE 6

Comment: Browser-specific problems are usually caused by client-side code (and thus not by server-side code such as JSF). Do you have some JavaScript code which submits a form onload, for example? Perhaps there's some unforeseen browser-specific JS condition which caused it to be triggered in IE.

Comment: I didn't implement any validation rules

Comment: Did I tell anything about validation? Please re-read the comment and answer it directly instead of coming back with a totally irrelevant comment.

Comment: Thanks BalusC for your quick response.  I do onload a javascript to reset the timeout on every page.  I will look into that.

Comment: sorry, but the validation comment was before i saw your answer.

Comment: I removed the onload on the current and target pages, but didn't help. IE is still rendering the current page.  Note: IE also renders the target page.

Comment: Well, this problem is hard to nail down without seeing a concrete copy'n'paste'n'runnable example. The symptoms are not recognizeable as any of "classic" bugs or beginner's mistakes. So there's must be a huge bug or mistake elsewhere. Easist is to copy the offending code into a blank sandbox project and then trim as much as possible irrelevant code until you end up with a fullworthy SSCCE. See also http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info

Comment: BalusC, You were correct in the beginning - I did have a jquery script that looked for capturing the window (browser) close event.  After I removed the jquery, IE is NOT rendering the current page any more.  Now I need to figure out why only IE is affected by the jquery script and how to avoid that.  Thanks again for the help.

Comment: You're welcome. I reposted it as an answer. If you still stucks on figuring the jQuery specific issue, feel free to ask a new question, now in the right context. Note that notifying the server about browser close event is extremely unreliable. There's means of a race condition and there's no guarantee that the ajax request ever arrive in its entirety in the server side. You might want to elaborate the concrete functional requirement as well, so that a more robust solution can be suggested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is unrelated to JSF. Browser-specific problems are usually caused by client-side code such as HTML/CSS/JS and not by server-side code such as JSF. This particular issue is recognizeable as a JavaScript problem. You need to check if there isn't any JavaScript code which performs some task during onload / DOM-ready such as auto-submitting a form. The phase listener trace namely suggests that a POST request is been performed (phases #2 until with #5 normally appear during postback only).

Most likely there's some unforeseen browser-specific JS condition which caused the POST request to be triggered in MSIE.